# proving an inequality is true in $R$

Tags: real-analysis

suppose that a,b and c are real numbers such that $|a-b| < c$ where $c > 0$, prove that $|a| < c+|b|$.

I think triangle inequality could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $-|t|\leq t\leq |t|$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$, we have that

> $a = a-b + b \leq |a-b| + |b|$.

and also that

> $a = a-b + b \geq -|a-b| - |b|$.

Joining the two inequalities, we get

> $-|a-b| - |b|\leq a \leq |a-b| + |b|\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ |a|\leq |a-b| + |b|< c+|b|$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is here, about the 2nd line down:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Mathematical_expression_of_the_constraint_on_the_sides_of_a_triangle

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|a - b| < c \iff b - c < a < b + c. $
Then use triangle inequality on the right inequality.